# Jennings variable vacuum capacitor

Tags: electronics, repair, capacitance

I have a Jennings CVDD 500 vacuum capacitor which is not working. Think it's a mechanical problem because I have another one and it works.

The symptom is that it is always electrically shorted.

[image]

Comment: hi there, and welcome to the site! I'd love to get my hands on one of these :-) however I don't understand what your question is here? Would you edit above to make clear what you have done so far, and what specific question you're looking to have answered now? This will help get you a quality answer.

Comment: I've made an edit which I think encapsulates the problem as I understand it.

Comment: What have you done so far to attempt to repair or troubleshoot it besides checking the resistance between the poles?

Comment: Please can you edit this to be in the form of a question that can be answered?

Answer (score 2):

Now solved (!)

- fact: the capacitor inner part is now totally at the out position - meaning minimum capacitance.
- to increase to max capacitance the brass part (see picture) must be pressed in.
- usually the inner part is automatically sucked to the inner position by vacuum.
- with the screw turning the inner part is pulling out.
- **Just now we pressed the brass part down/in and we heard a terrible scratch noise.
  It seems the capacitor plates inside were scratched and destroyed... the capacitor is totally broken.**

Maybe earlier in regular use it was arcing, became hot and the copper plates were burned and welded now together...

I bought this a few years ago and didn't have the equipment to build them in and test them.
Now I have some experience witt them - "I paid some money for this experiment - but I learned"
(but the other one is running well)